# array returning error in c

Tags: c, arrays, return

I am getting an error in the return line. "Incompatible pointer to integer conversion returning 'int (*)[2]' from a function with result type 'int'" can someone explain what is theory behind this error and how to fix it? still I am getting right result, but don't know about this error. (hints: I am very beginner )
here is my testing code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
/* two diminsanl array testing*/
int array_function(int phase,int array[][2]);
int main()
{
    int phase =1;
    int array[][2]={};
    array_function(phase, array);

    phase =2;
    array_function(phase, array);
    return 0;
}

int array_function(int phase, int array[][2])
{
    if(phase==1)
{
    array[0][0]=1;
    array[0][1]=2;
    array[1][0]=3;
    array[1][1]=4;
}
    if(phase==2)
{
    printf("%d\n",array[0][0]);
}
return array;  //<------------- error line
}
```

Comment: In c/c++, functions don't return an array. In c++, you should return a vector. Also, in c/c++, an array is passed by reference, so the function is modifying the original array.

Comment: An array is passed by the value of the pointer to the array, which is a reference to the array, and and thus as @CroCo said, is modifies the original (passed) array.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all, your function is expecting an `int` return, but you're trying to return an `int[][]`.

And, you can't return an array by value in c. You'll need to return a pointer, or wrap the array as part of a `struct`.

Comment: I try this return **array and it work. Is that the way? Thanks.

Comment: I'm confused though. You're passing an array to a function, modifying it, and then returning it. why not just make it a void return?

Comment: ok. thanks again. You know, beginner thinks hard way for simple problem:)

Answer (score 0):

You have `int` as return type of function ( `int` array_function() ) but are trying to return a pointer(`return array;`). Since it look that you don't need to return anything just have the return type as `void` or `return 0`. Since array is passed by reference it automatically gets the changes that you do to it inside the function.

Comment: I think you are already passing your array by f=reference, you don't need to return the array. Just change the return type to void or write `return 0`

Answer (score 0):

***First*** this line, is not a legal assignment:

```
int array[][2]={};
```

For what you are doing, this line would work:

```
int array[][2]={0,0,0,0};
```

***second*** As others have pointed out, this line is attempting to return `int[][]`.  Two problems with this, 1) C cannot return the value representation of an array of ints, (although it can return pointers, such as `int **`, you don't need to here.  See note at bottom).  And 2) the prototype clearly calls for `int`

```
return array;  //<------------- error line
```

For now, simply change the line to:

```
return 0;
```

Those two changes will result in your code populating `array[][]`  with no errors.

***Note:*** because you are passing your array by reference, ( `array_function(phase, array);` ) the values assigned to array within `array_function()` are made available back in the `main()` function without having them returned as a `return`.  (i.e. `int ** array_function(phase, array)` )

Answer (score 0):

If you statically create an array you have to specify both dimensions.
Arrays are passed as pointers and if you pass a static array it is good practice to give the dimensions in the parameters of the function. Simply pass the arrays name to any function even if you allocated it dynamically. If you want to return an array you should return an int* or int** for a 2D array.

Let's say you want to create an array in a function and let the caller have it.

```
int *createArray(int size)
{
    int *array = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    return array;
}
```

You can call this function from your main.

```
int *list;

list = createArray(2);
```

And modify list like any other array.

This is your code properly.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* two diminsanl array testing*/
void array_function(int phase, int array[2][2]);

int main()
{
    int phase = 1;
    int array[2][2];
    array_function(phase, array);

    phase = 2;
    array_function(phase, array);
    return 0;
}

void array_function(int phase, int array[2][2])
{
    if (phase == 1)
    {
        array[0][0] = 1;
        array[0][1] = 2;
        array[1][0] = 3;
        array[1][1] = 4;
    }
    if (phase == 2)
    {
        printf("%d\n",array[0][0]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, first of all, the type of the expression `array` in `array_function` is `int (*)[2]`, or "pointer to 2-element array of `int`".

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operator, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration, an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

When you call `phase_array` from `main`, like so:

```
array_function(phase, array);
```

the expression `array` has type "2-element array of 2-element array of `int`"; since it is not the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, it is converted to an expression of type "pointer to 2-element array of `int`", and its value is set to the address of the first element (`&array[0]`).  This *pointer* value is what gets passed to `array_function`.

In the context of a function parameter list, declarations of the forms `T a[N]` and `T a[]` will be interpreted as `T *a`; all three declare `a` as a pointer to `T`.  So,

```
int array_function(int phase, int array[][2])
```

is the same as

```
int array_function(int phase, int (*array)[2])
```

Which brings us to your error message: you've declared `array_function` to return an `int` (which you don't ever use in your `main` function, btw), but the type of the expression `array` is `int (*)[2]`; hence the error message.  The two types are not *compatible", and the compiler flags this as an error.

Since you've passed the *address* of the first element of `array` to `array_function`, any changes you make to the array contents will be reflected in `main`, so you really don't need to return the array.  As others have suggested, just change the type of the function to `void` and don't return anything.